# Javascript and Variable assistance

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, var

(Rephrasing question from earlier) So here is the assignment:

First, you will have to calculate a cost for the weight of the parcel. The user will enter the total weight of their parcel into the text field. The schedule is as follows…

0 – 150 lbs $20.00 per pound 
| 151 – 300 lbs $15.00 per pound 
| 301 – 400 lbs $10.00 per pound 
Do not allow the user to enter a weight that is < 0 or > 400. If they do, output an error message in red to div#results and ‘return’ out of the function.

Next, the user will choose a discount amount (for whatever reason, does not matter). You will need to apply whatever discount amount is chosen. (50% off, 20% off, none).

This is what I have done so far. Variable aren't declared yet, just wrote them in.

```
function calcTotal() {

var msg;
var weight = parseInt( document.getElementById("weight").value );
var discount;
var total;

if( weight >= 0 && weight <= 150 ) {

    total = weight * 20 
}   
else if( weight >150 && weight <= 300 ) {

    total = weight * 15 
}   
else if( weight >300 && weight <= 400 ) {

    total = weight * 10 
}

if( document.getElementById("50%").selected == true ) {

total = total * 0.50;
}

if( document.getElementById("25%").selected == true ) {

total = total * 0.25;
}

if( document.getElementById("none").selected == true ) {

total = total;
}
```

Is this somewhat correct so far?

Can't seem to figure out how to apply the discount based on what the user selects. The discounts are 3 radio buttons. Do i need to apply an id to each radio button?

Comment: When you say out loud "if weight is greater than zero or less than 150", you *imply* "or weight is less than 150". JavaScript is not so good at picking up on implications, you have to tell it what you want ;)

Comment: In your code, if weight is >= 0 it will always enter the first statement (because it will always be true) - you want to limit to the range 0-150 you need to make sure both conditions are true (w >= 0 AND w <=150) ; Same applies to all other if statements

Comment: I would also pass weight and discount as parameters to the function; and don't forget to handle the case when w < 0 or w > 400 (and set the message accordingly) - return msg at the end and voila :)

Comment: @blurfus "I would also pass weight and discount as parameters to the function." What do you mean by this? Thanks.

Comment: see my answer for that

Comment: You know, it is quite meaningless to update code each time you solve some part of it because then it ends up as a question with correct, working code without actually anything to answer - therefore not a question

Comment: lol, I keep updating with new questions.

Comment: I would suggest abstracting your data for the rules into an object and then reading from that in the function. It then makes your logic much simpler and cleaner. I would suggest using 1 as the lower bound for the Tier1 price group as it simplifies you edge case (0 is out of range). See my answer/fiddle for an example.

Comment: Yes, see answer by @MatúšDúbrava for what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to use && (AND) instead of || (OR) because you want both conditions to be met not just one. First IF statement will process value -1000 as TRUE (as well as any other value because your interval is from 0 to infinity plus from minus infinity to 150) because it satisfies the second part of the first condition.

Second, the formula is correct but you have to convert percents into 0-1 interval. 100% = 1, 0% = 0 and x% = x/100. Then it should work without any problems.

Last thing to do is that you need to pass the values into your function:

```
function calcTotal(weight, discount) {
    // do the calculation with passed values, you do not need to declare them here anymore
}
```

Or you need to set values right inside of that function, e.g.:

```
function calcTotal() {
    var discount = $("#inputField").val();  // using jQuery, where inputField is element
                                            // from which the value is taken e.g. < input >
    ...
}
```

To display the final output, add this to your function:

```
$("body").append("<div id='output'>" + output + "</div>"); // using jQuery, watch for single/double quotes
```

and style it with css to be in the center:

```
#output {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I want to now add the message "Your total cost is: ......" showing the total cost plus the discount (based on what user selected) with dollar sign for the output.

Comment: Add the message where?

Comment: Add it to the webpage as the result/ouput when the user clicks the button to calculate.

Comment: doh, add it where and how to webpage? as a value to some existing element prepared for this? or dynamically create new element and place it somewhere onto the webpage, show is as an alert, or modal window?

Comment: Just so it comes up in the center of the webpage. Something like "<div>Your total cost is: $ " + total </div>"

Comment: now I have also added how to dynamically create div with output

Comment: Okay, i'll give this a try after I come back from work.

Comment: I'm getting a "function is not defined" problem. My variables must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle that you should be able to get what is going on pretty quickly.

http://jsfiddle.net/a58rR/3/

I used a touch of jQuery just to get the bindings on the UI elements.

I hope this is not for a class and you copy this wholesale! ;)

Basically, I put all your Tier pricing into one object.

```
Tiers = [{
    nPrice: 20,
    nWeightMin: 1,
    nWeightMax: 150
}, {
    nPrice: 15,
    nWeightMin: 151,
    nWeightMax: 300
}, {
    nPrice: 10,
    nWeightMin: 301,
    nWeightMax: 400
}];
```

Then, your function will calculate based on the entered weight and discount selected, determine the Tier, validate the weight, update the UI with a message if out of range, calculate the final price and apply any discount, and update the UI with the total price:

```
function calculatePrice() {
    console.log('Begin Calc');
    var _nW = document.getElementById('nParcelWeight').value * 1;
    var _nD = document.getElementById('aDiscounts').value * 1;
    var _nP = 0;
    var nTotalPrice = 0;
    var _TotalPrice = document.getElementById('nPrice');
    var _nMaxWt = Tiers[Tiers.length - 1].nWeightMax; 
    // Using the last Tier keeps the max weight dynamic no matter how many tiers you add as long as they are in order

    console.log('Max Weight: ' + _nMaxWt);
    console.log('Weight: ' + _nW);
    console.log('Discount: ' + _nD);

    if (isNaN(_nW) || _nW < 1 || _nW > _nMaxWt) {

        // Throw/Display an out of range error here  
        console.log('Yep, out of range');
        document.getElementById('uiFeedback').innerHTML = 'The number is out of range.';
    } else {
        // reset if valid
        document.getElementById('uiFeedback').innerHTML = '';
    }

    // Find Tier
    for (var i = 0; i < Tiers.length; i++) {
        console.log('we are in loop:' + i);
        if (_nW >= Tiers[i].nWeightMin && _nW <= Tiers[i].nWeightMax) {
            _nP = Tiers[i].nPrice;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log('Tier: ' + i);
    console.log('Price: ' + _nP);

    // Calculate Discount
    if (_nD != 1) _nD = 1 - _nD; // (20%==.20, but that would be .80 of the Price, etc)

    // Calc Price
    nTotalPrice = (_nP * _nW * _nD);
    _TotalPrice.value = nTotalPrice;
}
```

The html will look something like this:

```
<div id='uiFeedback'></div>Parcel Weight:
<input id='nParcelWeight' value='0'>Discount:
<select id='aDiscounts'>
    <option value='1'>none</option>
    <option value='.2'>20%</option>
    <option value='.5'>50%</option>
</select>
<hr>Price:
<input id='nPrice'>
```

And your CSS at a minimum might just color your messaging:

```
#uiFeedback {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here are the bindings, which you could do with inline onChanges or raw js attach events:

```
$(function () {
    $('#nParcelWeight,#aDiscounts ').on('change', function () {
        calculatePrice();
    });
})
```

Comment: This is different from what we learned, although it looks promising. Any way I can PM you my entire code to show you how we learned? I'm getting this frustrating error message saying my function is not defined. Don't understand why and cant fix the problem.

Comment: @user3389685 Sure. williambq at gmail dot com.